# Unable to display the thumbnail in the status update

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a facebook app, where I need to display a thumbnail of my website's logo as the facebook status if any users likes my website.

I have added the meta tag in the head of the web page like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mydomain.com/images/admin/bg/PAP.png">
```

but it is displaying some other image on Facebook.  I also check in the [facebook debug site](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) which actually showed the logo of the web-site but it is not being updated on Facebook instead some other pic being updated on Facebook.

What is the problem and what may be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem on in.affinity.com , but image displays fine on affinity.com.
I tried hosting image on other server , with different url and it worked.
Try this if not working tel me your site , i'll look to it.
Cheers.

Comment: I tried with different URL, but still its not working its taking some other image

Comment: Can you tell me your site? and new image url?

Comment: i cant see any like button there.And many people are facing same thing , but its in a case of addthis .are you using addthis?

Comment: hey no just register in the website and once to register go to invite tab there u will find the facebook icon click on fb icon

Comment: This is a tag which i have got from fb dev forum ,<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.onjd.com/design05/images/PH2/WableAFC205.jpg" /> And this tag was written on your site ,<meta property="og:image images/admin/bg/PAP.png" content="http://styletag.com/images/admin/bg/PAP.png"/>

Comment: The try to ask your doubt [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/).And i did see your image but when i like the page only top of the image is displaying.

Comment: Actually that should not be the image. The Image should be styletag logo itself

Comment: @Linus Kleen Do I have to add other elements of Meta or just using only Meta is enough